# Snapshots tests locally vs on Percy

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer, snapshot, jest-puppeteer

I have a problem with snapshot testing.
Tests I take locally are generating snapshots that look like they supposed to (i.e a table in the right place, popups, etc..). But then when Percy.io runs the same tests for some reason the snapshots looks different: one column and popups shifted a bit, In chrome and firefox.

What could cause this difference?